# Posting a visualization to a website

Tags: web-mapping, carto

I'm hoping this is an easy question because I'm a pretty novice web dude:

I've made a visualization in CartoDB, but rather than simply embedding as an iframe, I'd prefer to get the javascript code of the visualization, so I can tweak it once I post it on my blog (to add buttons, etc.).

Where do I get the code to post into my blog page?

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB.js is what you want. It's a JavaScript library that allows you to embed CartoDB maps on your own website.

Check it out here: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you need is CartoDB.js

You can check a great course about this in the following link:
http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up.html